# Recursive calls to function passed as a parameter of another method via Consumer interface

Tags: java, function, parameters

given this code in Java:

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class Main {
    
    int element;
    public Main subclass;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Main m1 = new Main(3);
        Main m2 = new Main(0);
        m1.subclass = m2;

        m1.foo(Main::getElement, m1::setElement1);
        m1.foo(Main::getElement, m1::setElement2);

    }
    
    Main(int element)
    {
        this.element = element;
    }
    
    public int getElement()
    {
        return this.element;
    }
    
    public void setElement1(int n)
    {
        this.element = n;
    }
    
    public void setElement2(int n)
    {
        this.element = 2*n;
    }
    
    public void foo(Function<Main, Integer> resourceGetter, Consumer<Integer> resourceSetter)
    {
        resourceSetter.accept(5);
        System.out.println(resourceGetter.apply(this));
        
        if(subclass != null)
            this.subclass.foo(resourceGetter, resourceSetter);
    }
    
}
```

Let's focus on the `main` and, specifically, on the two method calls: `m1.foo(Main::getElement, m1::setElement1)` and `m1.foo(Main::getElement, m1::setElement2)`. In the first case, when the program reaches the line: `this.subclass.foo(resourceGetter, resourceSetter)`, the `foo` method is called in the subclass using the method `m1.setElement1` and in the second one, using the method `m1.setElement2`. Imagine that we would want to call the same method but with an instance of subclass, so that in the first case we would be calling `foo` with `this.subclass.setElement1` and in the second scenario, with `this.subclass.setElement2`.

Given the fact that the functions should remain `public` (`static` option would not be a solution for this), is there any way of inserting the setter as a parameter so that subclass can call its own setter?

I thought about an ugly and non-extensible way that is basically doing a enum of all functions that can be used as a parameter of foo function and passing that enum value as a parameter to the foo function so that it knows which functions to call each time.

Comment: You appear to be rather hopelessly confused about what a subclass is which makes the entire question a non sequitur. In your code, the variable `subclass` is wrong, that should be `wrappedInstance` perhaps - classes are like 'dog', and a variable points at a specific instance of it. Whose reified type may or may not be a subclass, the point is that it shouldn't matter. What I gather you want has nothing to do with subclasses; you want to pass a function that first [A] extracts the wrapped instance from the field `wrappedInstance`, and then calls `setElement1` on _that_.

Comment: Untangle this code; once you understand what subclasses are, eliminate that part from this code and call it `wrappedInstance`, then reformulate your question. Are you asking about how to craft a function that will extract the wrapped instance from an instance, then extract the wrapped instance from _that_, but no further? That's.. kinda weird. I can foresee 'do not unwrap', I can foresee 'unwrap once', and I can foresee' continue to unwrap until that field is `null`'. But, 'unwrap exactly twice'?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking. What are you trying to achieve and why is Consumer important, as passing in `m1::setElement1` is bound with `m1` not with another instance.